# Rails Routes - link_to singular resource with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

so this is stumping me im not the best when it comes to routes at all, but what i am trying to achieve seems simple. what i have is a feature that is currently only accessible by a superuser and now i would like to extend that functionality to a portal_administrator. now to access the page you need a link_to that looks like this

```
 = link_to('Data', portal_datum_path(current_portal.id), :id => :super_user_data_link)
```

which is routed with a match

```
 match '/portal_data/:id', :controller => 'portal_data', :action => 'show', :as => 'portal_datum'
```

now this works just fine you end up with a url that has a id params. which is used in the page that it routes to. in fact there is a before filter that makes sure there is a id.

```
  def load_portal
    @portal = Portal.find(params[:id])
  end
```

this would enable the susperuser to see what portal he was in just by looking at the url. now that i am extending this to the users i dont want them to see what portal id they are in, so i thought i would use a singular resource something along the following.

```
 = link_to('Data', portal_data_path, :id => :super_user_data_link)
```

with a

```
 match '/portal_data' => "portal_data#show"
```

so it routes to the same place but keeps the url clean. but obviously this dosent work. even if i hard code the before filer to accept the first portal it jsut throws a error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"portal_data", :action=>"show"}
```

but if i rake my routes its there?

i am sure what i am doing wrong is obvious any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i had to do was make the :id an optional parameter like so...

```
match '/portal_data(/:id)'
```

And it works :) then in the controller look for...

```
def load_portal
  @portal = Portal.find(params[:id] || current_portal.id)
end
```

...an portal id on the account if there wasn't one in the params.